# Why is this formula true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading my probability book when I found the following formula about 3 events

$$A \cup (B \cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$$

Can you explain me why this formula is true? I can't find a proof and it feels wrong.

EDIT: fixed the symbols

Comment: This follows from the fact that set union distributes over intersection.

Comment: I think a standard notation is $A \cup (B \cap C)$.  The Latex for this is "A \cup (B \cap C)".

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find the symbols in mathjax.

Comment: Use [Venn-diagrams](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) to make a picture. This might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of sets, this is the distributivity of union w.r.t. intersection (and conversely):
$$A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C),\qquad A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C).$$

*Some details for the first formula* :

As $B\cap C\subset B$ and $C$, we have $A\cup(B\cap C)\subset A\cup B$ and $A\cup(B\cap C)\subset A\cup C$, so $A\cup(B\cap C)\subset (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$.

Conversely, if $x\in(A\cup B)$ and $(A\cup C)$, then either $x\in A$, whence $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$, or $x\notin A$. In this case, $x\in B$ and $x\in C$, so $x\in B\cap C$, *a fortiori* $x\in A\cup(B\cap C)$.

Comment: So it's something i should just take for granted and not wonder where it came from?

Comment: It's easy to check. I can give some details if you wish.

Comment: I would love that.

Comment: This is not really an answer. It simply asserts the thing being asked about.

Comment: @Henning Malkholm: It translates in terms of sets. I'm not sure the O.P. does the translation in a correct way.

Comment: @Thomas: Done, mylord!

Comment: Thank you for the answer !

Answer (score 1):

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_Distributes_over_Intersection

has both a proof and a Venn diagram answering your question

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

In both $(A\cup B)$ and $(A\cup C)$ you have the whole set $A$ so you can definitely describe the right side as $A\cup (\dots)$. In a union, you do not throw any elements away so from the first therm you are left with $B$ and from the second with $C$. Then you just intersect them to get $A\cup (B\cap C)$.